# For Responsive website should i use Pixels or percent Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i aim to design Responsive web page .i am new to jquery , can you please suggest me From where  I should start?

should i give values to attributes  i.e height,width in pixcels or Percentage ?

[image]

I have created something but that is not displayed properly on Tabs.

Comment: before you try too much, have you tried Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/) - it would simplify your task

Answer (score 2):

you would do it with CSS and media queries & max-width min-width.

Percentage would be better though!

check out this article: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

example:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Percentages but I recommend you to checkout http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: So why does Bootstrap use hard pixel values?

Comment: @media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    max-width: 1170px;
}

Answer (score 1):

Percentages help with a *fluid* design, but to be truly *responsive* you should look at CSS media queries. A responsive design changes the layout (and sometimes the content) depending on factors such as screen size.

Answer (score 1):

For responsive websites you should prefer using percentage values.

However, there are several frameworks already out for developers to use which will make it easier to build responsive websites. Given below are some:

1. Skeleton Framework: www.getskeleton.com [this I use]
2. Bootstrap: getbootstrap.com
3. 960 Grid System: 960.gs

You may use either of them to build excellent responsive websites. Just download the script and extract them to the folder of your website. Copy the css and js files to respective folders and call them through your index.html using link tag.

Better call javascript at the endy of the HTML file, just before the body ends.

Start using the framework for your website and I am sure everything will get fixed

Good luck !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Pixel based is so called fixed layout, percentage based is so called fluid layout and em based is so called elastic layout. You need to consider which option is best fit for your website. But mine choice would be elastic layout but it's a difficult, so choose fluid layout for your site would be great.

For responsive design my choice is bootstrap. You can search more framework is available online.

Answer (score 0):

You should use any of the relative units like `percentage` or `em`. Google `em` to find more.

As for being responsive, you should use media queries.

For example: if you want all of your panes to stack vertically for smaller screens (lets say width < 800 px). Then you would do something like this:

```
.pane-selector{
  //Define style for widths > 800 px
}

@media(max-width: 800px){

  .pane-selector{
    width:100%;
    //And whatever you wanna do
  }
}
```

But! There are many frameworks that you can use to build sites like Twitter Bootstrap, Zurb etc.  These are full fledged CSS frameworks that provide you with bare-bones css layouts and also UI elements and components. There are also minimal CSS layout skeletons. Google it and you'll find loads.